# Friedrichs Inequality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators, index-theory

I'm a little confused with the following proof of Friedrichs inequality in Lawson's & Michelsohn's book *[Spin geometry](https://books.google.it/books?id=xfgbDAAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, page 194, Theorem 5.4.

I don't understand why the last inequality, i.e.
$$
C(\|\varphi u\|_{\Omega,L_{s-m}^2}+\|P\varphi u\|_{\Omega,L_{s-m}^2})\leq C'\|u\|_{\Omega, L_{s-1}^2},
$$ holds.
 Additionally, I'm confused with how to apply the argument repeatedly by taking a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$ as above stated such that we can get the final inequality we desired in the theorem?

Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks!

Comment: As explained in the text, $P(\varphi u)$ consists of $\varphi Pu$ and a sum of derivatives of $u$ up to order $m-1$, where $m$ is the order of $P$. To compute the $s-m$-Sobolev norm, you have to differentiate this up to $s-m$ times, then take the $L^2$ norm. This gives $s-1$ derivatives in total and bounds the second term on the left. For the first term, you get the estimate from the product rule.

Comment: And to repeat the argument, assume $K=\Omega_0\subset\subset\Omega_1\subset\subset\cdots$ as in the book. Apply the estimate to bound the $s-i$-Sobolev norm on $\Omega_i$ by the $s-i-1$-Sobolev norm on $\Omega_{i+1}$, and note that $u$ remains in the kernel of $P$ all the time.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Could you please  write your answer with more details? I’m actually still a little confused with your explanation. Thanks

Comment: I believe that you should try to follow the steps in the book one by one to see how they prove the claims. In the end, it boils down to use the product rule for differentiation over and over again.